# How to get rid of points in bw image and be left with connected pixels?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, image-morphology

I have the following image (image is fully black, don't mind the border)

[image]

I want to be left only with the (1 pixel-wide) line, and be rid of all the points (some of which are actually a couple of pixels).

I know this is rather easy, but i am out of ideas for now :(

What I have tried:

a morphology operation for opening (erode + dilate) - left me with either nothing or the same

blob detection - doing [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) would maybe work after dilation, but it crashes with no error (windows exception), and I have no time to debug opencv.

---

would love any idea that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following, just to get done with it. I am sure something smarter could have been done:

```
    thread_defect_mask_clean = thread_defect_mask_noisy.copy()
    ret, connected_components_labels = cv2.connectedComponents(thread_defect_mask_noisy.astype('uint8'), connectivity=8)
    for label in range(1, ret):
        label_count = np.count_nonzero(label == connected_components_labels)
        if label_count < self._min_thread_defect_size:
            thread_defect_mask_clean[label == connected_components_labels] = 0
```

This counts the size of each connected component, and enforces a threshold (5 here)

Comment: If there are a lot of dots, this will become expensive. Consider computing a histogram of the labeled image, then find the label with most pixels. I upvoted this because it's a good solution and the other two definitely not. But look into the area opening, it's exactly what you're after. Though OpenCV likely doesn't have it.

Comment: @Cris why other solution are not good ? could you elaborate ?

Comment: @CrisLuengo By area opening you mean something other than erode+dilate?

Comment: @antoine, your answer is not bad, but it will never distinguish short lines from longer lines, it is really limited to dots vs lines. The 3rd answer will delete diagonal lines, it explicitly preserves things where there are two 4-connected pixels (again, doesn't generalize to larger things you might want to delete). This answer here has a `_min_thread_defect_size` parameter, which can be set to whatever size threshold you want.

Comment: @Gulzar, erode+dilate is a *structural opening*. There are many more types of openings, which have the same properties but cannot be written as a combination of erosion and dilation. The area opening is an example of *parametric opening*. It's a shame that most image processing books don't go deep enough into the topic, Mathematical Morphology is really fascinating and very broad.

Comment: @antoine, where I said "dots" I meant isolated pixels or groups of two pixels at most. Dots could be larger than that too, I guess.

Comment: @Gulzar, scikit-image has an area opening: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.area_opening

Comment: @CrisLuengo didn't know about the nice functions in scikit.image. How about https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects wouldn't it be exactly that?

Comment: @Gulzar, yes, that one is the right one to use for binary images.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a custom erode function that count the non black pixel in a 3x3 window, if there is one, the pixel value is untouched, if there is no, the pixel will become black.

In C++ it looks like (EDIT : I've added a blur based method which is much more faster):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <chrono>

int main(void)
{
  cv::Mat input = cv::imread("salt.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  imshow("input", input);

  cv::Mat thresh;
  // threshold the input just to be sure to get only white or black pixels.
  cv::threshold(input, thresh, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

  cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8UC1);
  mask.at<unsigned char>(1,1)=0;
  cv::imshow("mask", mask);
  cv::Mat output1 = thresh;
  cv::Mat output2 = thresh;

  { // first method : iterate over all pixels (very slow but didactic)
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int r=1; r<thresh.rows-1; r++)
    {
      for(int c=1; c<thresh.cols-1; c++)
      {
        cv::Rect roi(c-1,r-1,3,3);
        cv::Mat window = thresh(roi);
        cv::Scalar val = cv::sum(window.mul(mask));
        if(val[0]==0)
          output1.at<unsigned char>(r,c) = 0;
      }
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
    std::cout << "iterating method: " << duration.count() << std::endl; // 116965µs

    cv::imshow("output", output1);
  }

  { // optimized method : use blur and threshold
    cv::Mat blur, output2=thresh, thresh2;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cv::blur(thresh, blur, cv::Size(3,3));

    cv::threshold(blur, thresh2, 60, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    output2.mul(thresh2);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
    std::cout << "blur method: " << duration.count() << std::endl; // 378µs

    cv::imshow("blur", output2);
  }

  auto diff = (output1 - output2) * 255;
  std::cout << "diff norm: " << cv::norm(diff) << std::endl; // 0

  while(1)
  {
    if(27 ==cv::waitKey(0))
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

[image: Processed Image]

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] - Didn't notice it needs to be 1x1 pixels line

Like you said - I ignored the border

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread("dumpster/eLIRj.png")
cv2.imwrite("dumpster/masking/1.png", img)

# convert to grayscale (single channel)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite("dumpster/masking/2.png", gray)

# otsu thresholding
otsu = cv2.threshold(
    gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imwrite("dumpster/masking/3.png", otsu)

# erode with horizontal and vertical lines (2x1 pixels)
kernel = np.ones((2,1), dtype=np.uint8) 
erosion = cv2.erode(otsu, kernel, iterations = 1)
kernel = np.ones((1,2), dtype=np.uint8) 
erosion = erosion + cv2.erode(otsu, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2.imwrite("dumpster/masking/4.png", erosion)

# dilate whats left with 3x3 kernel
kernel = np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imwrite("dumpster/masking/5.png", dilated)

# create binary mask and apply it on thresholded, grayscale image
mask = dilated / 255
final = otsu * mask
cv2.imwrite("dumpster/masking/6.png", final)
```

Original image:
[image]

Dilated:
[image]

Final:
[image]

Comment: it looks like the resulting line is more than one pixel wide, isn't ?

Comment: you're correct, I missed that part. I'll edit and update my answer later to reflect that